# Loading external pages within a homescreen webapp on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm developing an app for iPhone which make use of jQueryMobile and the homescreen mode, and I have to reference to an external link during the page flow, but after clicking the link, it opens the page in a new safari window, is there a way to do this without opening the page in Safari, but doing so within the homescreen app.